# OpenMP: is it not possibe to use omp parallel for and omp task together? /error: work-sharing region may not be closely nested inside of work-sharing

Tags: c++, recursion, parallel-processing, openmp, shared-memory

In my c++ implementation, I have a recursive function and I call this recursive function inside a loop. I want to use OpenMP to create parallelism.

```
func caller(){

  #pragma omp parallel    
  {  
    #pragma omp for nowait    
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        #pragma omp single
        recursive_func(n);   
    }
  }

void recursive_func(n){

  if (x){
    #pragma omp task
    recursive_func(n-1);   
  }   
  else{
    #pragma omp task
    recursive_func(n-2);  
  }
}
```

I basically want the outer loop to be executed by many threads, but then when it comes to the recursive function, only one thread should start executing it and then the recursive calls should be handled with new tasks (that will come with `omp pragma task`)

However, I receive this compilation error:

> error: work-sharing region may not be closely nested inside of
> work-sharing, ‘critical’, ‘ordered’, ‘master’, explicit ‘task’ or
> taskloop’ region
> 68 |         #pragma omp single

Comment: 1. I wonder if the `nowait` is the problem 2. There is not much point in having a parallel loop where the the body is executed `single. How about if you put the `single` before the loop and don't make it parallel?

Comment: @VictorEijkhout yeah I get what you mean, the single defeats the purpose of the parallel there. I just wanted to have the recursive function excuted at the same time by many threads AND the recursive function being executed by different tasks everytime

Comment: @codertryer If you want to create new tasks within a work-sharing construct, you have to open a new ```omp parallel``` section within your recursive function. However, I advice against that as it will just overload the CPU and OpenMP will always start new threads instead of using its threadpool for the nested parallel section.

What problem do you actually want to solve?

Comment: @Homer512 OpenMP does not require the implementation to start new threads in many cases. Actually, AFAIK neither Clang nor GCC start new threads in simple cases (when the number of threads do not change): threads of the previous section are recycled.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Yeah, in simple cases. This is a nested case. I'll have to double-check where the specifications ask for this kind of behavior but you can easily see it with strace. If you nest your parallel sections, GCC's implementation will start new threads for the inner section.

Comment: @Homer512 I agree for the creation of new threads in nested cases (although I remember this can be tuned for GCC/Clang). However, there is no (need for) nesting here: tasks *can be scheduled* in parallel for loops and this not nesting. In such a case, the parallel section creates implicit tasks (the parallel for directive only share the work) and the sibling tasks of each implicit tasks are independent by design (this is a problem though here since the OP want them to be executed with a mutual exclusion). This is detailed in sections 1.3, 17.1 and 15.9.5 of the OpenMP 5.2 specification.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Okay, seems like you are correct about not needing nesting in this case. For the record, the lack of pooling for nested threads is explained here in line 429 https://code.woboq.org/gcc/libgomp/team.c.html

Answer (score 2):

You cannot put a `#pragma omp single` directive in a `#pragma omp for` region because the work of the for is already shared between threads and thus the instruction are *already guaranteed to be executed by only one thread* in this case (not to mention that the `single` directive end up doing a barrier unless you use the close `nowait`).

If you want two `recursive_func` call not to be called in parallel, then you an (implicit/explicit) synchronization is *required*.

One (pretty bad) way is to use a *critical section* (`#pragma omp critical`). The task in the critical section can be stolen/affected by/to other threads. This is only possible some threads reach a *scheduling point*. If there is no such a thread, then the task will be executed serially on the current thread. The end of a parallel region is a scheduling point (like barrier, taskloops, taskwait, etc.). Thus a thread *may* executes a task of the recursive function only after executing the parallel loops (at least its dedicated part). Even worse: a critical section is *not* a scheduling point and so other threads will likely end up waiting for nothing while there is some work to execute. You cannot *force* OpenMP to stop other thread executing the parallel loop unless you adds some additional synchronization that constraint the execution of the other threads.

An alternative (pretty bad) solution is to set a flag after all the recursive tasks has been scheduled so that the other threads will stop their work when they see the flag set. To force a thread to temporary stop executing the main loop until all the tasks has been executed, you can use a `#pragma omp taskyield` in a loop that iterates while an atomic value reaches a specific value (stating whether all the recursive tasks has been executed). However, OpenMP implementations may not execute the task in such a thread resulting in a very bad scheduling. Indeed, doing nothing in a `taskyield` is completely compliant with the standard (and actually many mainstream OpenMP implementations did not implement it in the past). Moreover, this method is complex to complement. Note a `barrier` cannot be used in this case and a `taskwait` is not much better than a `taskyield` since the scheduled tasks are children of the implicit tasks of the main parallel loop.

In general, parallel for loops and tasks does not fit well together. Moreover, trying to *force* a given schedule using tasks and synchronization primitives is tricky, if not flawed due to implicit hypothesis done on the target OpenMP implementation. In complex cases, using a *flat tasking model* can sometimes provide more flexibility than a hierarchical one.

A better solution is to split each iteration in 3 tasks and create tasks for each iteration (they can be merged manually although this is a bit tricky) and then tell to OpenMP that the recursive task are "more important" than others by setting a higher *priority* to such tasks. Moreover, if you do not want several call to `recursive_func` to be executed in parallel, you could use mutually-exclusive task dependencies. Finally, the tasks of the same iteration share same `inout` dependency variable so to be executed sequentially.

Here is an (OpenMP 5) example:

```cpp
void caller(int num)
{
    #pragma omp parallel    
    #pragma omp single
    {
        char* deps = new char[num];
        char criticalDep;

        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            #pragma omp task depend(out: deps[i]) priority(0)
            someWork1(i);

            #pragma omp task depend(inout: deps[i]) \
                             depend(mutexinoutset: criticalDep) \
                             priority(1)
            recursive_func(i);

            #pragma omp task depend(in: deps[i]) priority(0)
            someWork2(i);
        }

        delete[] deps;
    }
}

void recursive_func(int n) {
  if (x){
    #pragma omp task priority(1)
    recursive_func(n-1);   
  }   
  else{
    #pragma omp task priority(1)
    recursive_func(n-2);
  }
}
```

However, please note that:

- a compliant OpenMP implementations *can* completely ignore the task priorities (but *must* follow the dependencies);
- the *granularity* of the task should be carefully tuned as this solution can create more tasks than others despite being more flexible;
- an implementation may execute the tasks in an unwanted order and so you may need to tweak the priorities.